# Which layer of VGG19 should I use to extract feature

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras

Now, I want feature of image to compute their similarity. We can get feature using pre-trained VGG19 model in tensorflow easily. But VGG19 model has many layers, and I don't know which layer should I use to get feature. Which layer's output is appropriate for this problem?

```py
# I think this how is correct to extract feature
model = tf.keras.application.VGG19(include_top=True, 
                                   weight='imagenet')
input = model.input
output = model.layers[-2].output
extract_model = tf.keras.Model(input, output)
```

It's my infer that the more closer to last output, the more the model output powerful feature. But some tutorials says 'use `include_top=False` to extract feature' (e.g  [Image Captioning with Attention TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/image_captioning))

So, I don't know which layer should I use. Please try to help me here in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `include_top=False` may be used because the last 3 layers (for that specific model) are fully connected layers which are not typically good feature vectors. If the model directly outputs a feature vector, then you don't need it.

Most people use the last layer for transfer learning, but it may depend on your application. For example, [Gatys et. al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06576) show that the first few layers of VGG are sensitive to the style of the image and later layers are sensitive to the content.

I would probably try all of them in a hyperparameter search and see which gives the best performance. If by image similarity you mean the similarity of objects contained inside, I would probably start with the last layer.

Comment: I meant similarity of whole of image. It's not only object but also includes background.
Basically, when image similarity means similarity of object in image, I should use layer that closer to output. Whereas if I want to compare whole of image, I should set `include_top=False` and use last layer. That's ok?

Comment: Last layer, but may be worth doing a search.